# Is there a niche market for A&P mechanics with an aerospace engineering degree?

Tags: usa, aircraft-maintenance, airframe-and-powerplant

I've noticed a few people posting on this site who I would guess are aerospace engineers.

I am an A&P Mechanic, who is currently in the process of applying to college for an aerospace engineering degree.

My question is this:

Does a niche exist that would involve both skill sets, and will the A&P license/experience give me a competitive edge for hiring in some companies?

Answer (score 2):

There is certainly a niche for both skill sets. Part of aerospace engineering is considering maintenance. There are multiple types of positions where having an [A&P license](http://www.naa.edu/programs/what_is_an_ap_mechanic) would be a bonus.

- During the design of an aircraft, maintenance must be taken into account. Projected maintenance costs are important to the success of a design. Engineers must address this during the design of new parts.
- Manufacturing will have a lot of aspects in common with maintenance. Engineers must support manufacturing requirements in the design phase. Supporting emerging issues in manufacturing is also an important role.
- Engineering is also needed to support regular maintenance tasks. Problems come up that aren't covered in the manual, and engineers will need to advise on a solution.

Based on these subjects, the following are a few types of companies will have some positions where an A&P license could help:

- Designers of aerospace parts
- Manufacturers of aerospace parts
- Airline maintenance departments
- Maintenance, Repair, and Overhaul (MRO) companies

This focuses mostly on the commercial side of things. You can also find either civilian or military jobs supporting the military equivalent of these functions as well.